# Toolbar context menu showing inside toolbarbutton's xul panel

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I have a `toolbarbutton` that when clicked, shows a panel. When i right click the panel i'm getting the following:

[image: unwanted context menu]

This is the same context menu that shows when i click on the main toolbar or even the toolbarbuttons.

The xul is:

```
<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
  <toolbarbutton id="testToolbarIcon"
           image="chrome://myext/content/images/aicon.png"
           type="panel"
           class="toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional">
    <panel id="testPanel"
         type="arrow"
         level="parent">
      <vbox id="testbox" align="top" width="200" height="200">
        <label value="Test Label" />
        <textbox></textbox>
      </vbox>
    </panel>
  </toolbarbutton>        
</toolbarpalette>
```

Any idea on how to stop this behavior from passing to the panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an `click` event listener to the panel and [`.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault) and/or [`.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation) should do the trick, if memory served right.

Another way is simply not to use a `type="panel"` button, put the panel somewhere else (a popupset) and open the panel from js using `.openPopup()`. To get the button state right, you need to do a `button.open = true` when the popup is shown, and revert that once it is hidden again (at least that is what the download-indicator button does).

Comment: Hi @nmaier. Thanks for answering. I tried that on the panel and also on the toolbarbutton, but it always prevents also the right click contextmenu (copy,paste, etc) on the textbox. I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: Only prevent events if `.originalTarget === panel` then?

Comment: This is likely to work after doing validations for a bunch of things, (panel, labels, spacers, images, boxes etc), but i was trying to find if there's a more "native" way of preventing this.

Comment: Well, I suppose you could make it a regular toolbar button, put the panel in the popupset instead of being a child to the button and open the panel from js via `.openPanel(...)`. The only other regular panel button, the Downloads button, isn't `type="panel"` itself...

Comment: Yes. I tried ot that way too and it really looks like my best option. The only thing i'm missing is how to style the button as selected when i click it (see [this image](http://i.imgur.com/sXfzZaR.png?1) for the difference. Do you know how i can replicate it?

Comment: That will work. I was hoping there was some kind of property to separate the panel from the button, but this may be even better. Thank you and keep up the good work :)

Answer (score 0):

I have

```
<toolbarbutton id="search-button" label="Search" type="panel" oncommand="signage.onMenuItemCommand(event);" onclick="signage.emptyFn(event);" ondblclick="signage.emptyFn(event);"></toolbarbutton>
```

where

```
signage.emptyFn: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //event.stopPropagation();
},
```

And works fine!