# XUL How to separate button from menu in a menu-button

Tags: javascript, firefox, menu, firefox-addon, xul

I'm developing a Firefox plugin using XUL and i have got the following:

```
<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
    <toolbarbutton id="MYBUTTON_ID" type="menu-button" class="toolbarbutton-1" label="Menu" tooltiptext="Menu" oncommand="checkLogin();" popup="login-popup">
        <menupopup id="mymenu">
            <menuitem label="Menu 1" oncommand="toDo(); event.stopPropagation();"/>
            <menuitem label="Menu 2" oncommand="toDo(); event.stopPropagation();"/>
            <menuitem label="Menu 3" oncommand="toDo(); event.stopPropagation();"/>
        </menupopup>
    </toolbarbutton>
</toolbarpalette>
<popupset>
    <panel id="login-popup" backdrag="true" type="arrow" noautohide="false">
        <vbox flex="1">
            <hbox flex="1">
                <label control="user-label" width="60px" value="Username:"/>
                <textbox id="user"/>
            </hbox>
            <hbox flex="1">
                <label control="pwd-label" width="60px" value="Password:"/>
                <textbox id="pwd"  type="password"/>
            </hbox>
            <hbox>
                <checkbox label="Ricordami" checked="false"/>
            </hbox>
            <hbox flex="1">
                <spacer flex="1"/>
                <button id="pwd" width="30px" label="Login"/>
            </hbox>
        </vbox>
    </panel>
</popupset>
```

Now when i click on the "button" part of the menu button, i correctly get the login popup, but if i click on the arrow (the "menu" part) it shows the menupopup AND the login popup behind the menupopup because i think the "popup" event is fired also when i click on the arrow, but I only want the menupopup to appear. How to reach this? I'm new in XUL development.

Comment: I don't see the popup attribute documented for [toolbarbutton](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/toolbarbutton) or [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/button). I think the popup is shown by ```checkLogin()```

Comment: The popup is show by the `popup="login-popup"` attribute, `check_login()` is a javascript function I made that toggles my icon from grey to colors if the user is logged in.

Comment: Adding ```event.stopPropagation()``` to the ```oncommand``` attributes of ```menuitems``` did the trick for me if you didn't already set them (As described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18559716/392549)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have two `popup`s for a single `button` (although technically there is more than one).

1. Remove the `popup=` attribute.
2. [Show the popup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Method/openPopup) from your `oncommand`:

   ```
   document.getElementById("login-popup")
     .openPopup(event.originalTarget, 
                "after_start",
                 0, 0,
                 false, true,
                 event);
   ```
3. You might have to check the `.originalTarget` to be not a `menuitem` first to avoid having your `popup` trigger when clicking on such `menuitem`.

*Aside*: Please use unique-enough DOM ids/classes and unique-enough variable/function names in your overlays and overlay scripts, to avoid conflicts with other add-ons or the browser itself. See: [JavaScript Object Management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial/JavaScript_Object_Management)

Comment: Great! It works! Thanks! And this way I can also change the popup I want to show!